# How to add a existing custom checkout field in the account details tab - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom checkout select field with validation. I was able to show this field in the order in the backend and in the confirmation email. I added it with this code:

```
/*** ADD DOCKING STATION FIELD @ WC CHECKOUT ***/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'bbloomer_add_custom_checkout_field' );

function bbloomer_add_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) { 
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   $saved_docking_station = $current_user->docking_station;
   woocommerce_form_field( 'docking_station', array(        
  'type' => 'select',
  'class' => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
  'label' => 'Do you have a docking station/ loading dock on-site?',     
  'required' => true,
  'default' => $saved_docking_station,
  'options' => array(
        ''  => __( 'Choose an option' ),
        'No'    => __( 'No' ),
        'Yes'   => __( 'Yes' ),
        )
), $checkout->get_value( 'docking_station' ) ); 
}

/* Validate this field */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bbloomer_validate_new_checkout_field' );

function bbloomer_validate_new_checkout_field() {    
   if ( ! $_POST['docking_station'] ) {
  wc_add_notice( '<strong>Docking station</strong> is a required field.', 'error' );
}
}

/* Save & show this field @ WC orders & emails */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'bbloomer_save_new_checkout_field' );

function bbloomer_save_new_checkout_field( $order_id ) { 
if ( $_POST['docking_station'] ) update_post_meta( $order_id, '_docking_station', esc_attr( $_POST['docking_station'] ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order', 10, 1 );

function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_order( $order ) {    
$order_id = $order->get_id();
if ( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_docking_station', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>Docking station:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, '_docking_station', true ) . '</p>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_emails', 20, 4 );

function bbloomer_show_new_checkout_field_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
if ( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_docking_station', true ) ) echo '<p><strong>Docking station:</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_docking_station', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

I also want to show this field on the account page; in the tab Account details (/my-account/edit-account). It would be perfect if the value of the docking field is visible on the account page and that the users can change this value on the account page for future orders.

I wonder if it's even possible to show the exact same field on the account page? I can imagine that this is not possible because checkout fields and account (user) fields are different type of fields and therefore you can't use the same field for both purposes. However, I hope it's possible.